# Maximium of an Integral

Tags: r, max, integral, log-likelihood

I have an Integral in terms of parameters a,b,p,q.
My probability densitiy function of data x is

```
GB2PdfCalc=function(x){
  out=(abs(a)*x^(a*p-1))/(b^(a*p)*beta(p,q)*(1+(x/b)^(a))^(p+q))
  return(out)
}
```

I want to an integral of this using GB2PdfCalc:

```
    pdfIntegration<-function(x){
      [...]
      integral[i]=integrate(GB2PdfCalc,x[k],x[j])[1]
      integral=as.vector(integral,mode="numeric")                       
      return(integral)
    }

pdfIntegration(x)
```

However, I want to maximize this Integral in terms of a,b,p,q. Eventually, I want to calculate a Maximum Likelihood function. Using mle(pdfIntegration) or optim() didn't help me here.
Anybody got ideas?

Comment: could we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: Generally, I want to maximize function pdfIntegration in terms of a, b, p, and q using a numeric vector x.